# angularjs / javascript how to update factory created singleton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm pretty new to angularjs and javascript so I'm hoping you can help me figure this out. I have a factory creating a service singleton and I want it to subscribe to some events and update itself when those occur.

However, I'm not sure how to get a reference to the object created by the factory in this context. See "My Problem" in a code comment.

I would also appreciate any and all feedback on the way I'm using angular/js and what I could be doing better.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var coreMod = angular.module('CoreMod',['ng']);

coreMod.factory('accountService', accountService);
accountService.$inject=['$rootScope',
                        '$log',
                        '$http',
                        '$q',
                        '$localStorage',
                        '$sessionStorage',
                        'authService'];
function accountService($rootScope, $log, $http, $q, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, authService) {
    var accountService = {            
        CurrentAccount: null,
        logOut: logOut,
        _logIn: userLoggedIn//anyway to hide this?
    };
    $rootScope.$on('userLoggedIn', accountService._logIn);
    return accountService;    

    function userLoggedIn() {            
        $http({ method: 'get', url: msApiUrl + '/account/userinfo', timeout: 3000, warningAfter: 50 })//TODO: find a way to make these timinings default
            .success(function (result) {
            $log.info('User logs into api server successfully and gets response: ' + result);
            handleLoginMessage(result);
        }).error(function (result) {
            $log.warn('Error logging into api server. Response: ' + result);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('CriticalError', 'Error logging into api. Please clear your cache and try again. If this occurrs again please contact your system administrator. ');//TODO: configurable and localized message
        });
    };

    function handleLoginMessage(message) {
        var accountService = this; //my problem: this is undefined
        accountService.CurrentAccount={};
        accountService.CurrentAccount.emailHash = message.EmailHash;//TODO: are these case sensitive / can I control that
        accountService.CurrentAccount.organizationId = message.OrganizationId;
        accountService.CurrentAccount.username = message.Username;
        $localStorage.userInfo = accountService;
    };

    function logOut() {
        authService.logOut();
        $sessionStorage.$reset();
        $localStorage.userInfo = null;                     
    };
}
```

}());

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it how to hide `_logIn`? Is it the undefined with `var accountService = this;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the code line at all. Just remove:

```
var accountService = this;
```

`accountService` is an object literal that you have created with `var accountService = {...}` and your function `handleLoginMessage` is in the same scope. So the `accountService` variable should be accessible with-in `handleLoginMessage`.

If you want to hide `_logIn: userLoggedIn` then remove it from `accountService` object but then it is not accessible from outside of your service. Everything that's inside of `accountService` will be exposed to other controllers, services or factories that are injecting your factory.

Comment: Where do you `console.log` the `accountService` to see that it is undefined? Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0qmk8LkL/). (I've removed the http to simulate your service with-out a backend.)

Comment: It's defined now; some other change must have fixed that and made my workaround the problem. Thanks for the help.